# targetcli vs tgtd

Tags: iscsi, targetcli

I was reading about targetcli and have this confusion. in rhel 6, to configure iscsi target, iscsi-target-utils need to be installed but in rhel 7, targetcli need to be installed. Can't we use iscsi-target-utils on rhel7 and targetcli in rhel 6. is targetcli is advanced version of iscsi-target-utils.